# How to fit height of aside to body height

Tags: html, css, footer

1. i need to fit the height of aside to that of body without regard to how much content there is. As it is it gives me fig. 2 and i need to have figure 1.
2. I also need to have footer fit inside of body height. `position:absolute` does fit but overrides `margin:auto` which centers the body element. How do i align div elements
   Html code:

   `<html>
       <body>

       <header></header>

       <aside></aside>

       <footer></footer>

       </body> 
       </html>`

My css code is this:

```
  body{ width:920px;
    position:absolute;
    height:auto; }
aside { float:left;
    width:170px; }

 footer { float: right;
     background: #E7DBD3;
     clear:both; }
```

[image: Body and aside heights]

Comment: @Michel yea i did; a number of solutions: 1) float both aside and body left `aside{float:left} body{float:left}` 2) use tables ie wrap both of them in div  _wrapper_ then `.wrap{display:table} aside,body{display:table-cell}` 3) add margins and widths (Maybe not be the best solution) 4) use bootstrap 5) grids 6) use css/javascript/jQuery http://stugreenham.com/demos/fluid-width-with-a-fixed-sidebar/#js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set the top and bottom values of the aside.  Something like:

```
aside { 
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  width:170px; 
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Try setting `position:absolute`.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of what you have?  The code you posted is only partial.

Answer (score 0):

To specify height to the aside element irrespective of its content, use  position: absolute with required top and bottom values.

while Positioning the aside element, make sure it is positioned relative to the document body i.e ancestor of the aside element should be document body and not any other element.Mentioning the top and bottom values help to achieve the desired height of the aside element.

For example,if header is 60px in height and footer is 30px in height and aside should be in left side,then css code would be,

```
aside { 
  width: 250px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;    # to position after the header 
  bottom: 30px; # to end before the footer
  left: 0px;    # to position in the left side..Use right: 0px to position aside in the right side
}
```